# Sudoku java, wrote a program but doesn't pick up on repeated numbers

Tags: java, sorting, return, sudoku

i'm writing a Java program that verifies whether or not a set of 9x9, 2 dimensional array of integers is a possible solution of a sudoku puzzle. The problem is that the program I've written doesn't pick up on some integers which are side by side. For example, I put an 8 next to an 8 at 5x4 and it still returns true. Here are the methods to check the Rows by Columns and blocks of 3 by 3. Thank you in advanced

```
public class Sudoku{
    private static boolean sudoku= true;
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int input[][]= {{1,8,4,9,6,3,7,2,5},
                   {5,6,2,7,4,8,3,1,9},
                   {3,9,7,5,1,2,8,6,4},
                   {2,3,9,6,5,7,1,4,8},
                   {7,5,6,8,8,4,2,9,3},//repeated "8" here
                   {4,1,8,2,3,9,6,5,7},
                   {9,4,1,3,7,6,5,8,2},
                   {6,2,3,8,9,5,4,7,1},
                   {8,7,5,4,2,1,9,3,6}};

        RowXColumn(input);
        if(sudoku == true)
             Blocks(input);
        else{
        }

        System.out.println("True or false, is this a sudoku puzzle solution: " + sudoku);
    }
    public static void RowXColumn(int [][]b){
        for(int row= 0; row < a.length; row++){
            for(int col=0; col< a[row].length; col++){//checks rows
               int b= a[row][col];
               for(int x= row+1; x< a.length; x++){
                  if(b == a[x][col])
                     sudoku= false;
                  else
                     continue;
               }
               for(int y= col+1; y< a[row].length; y++){//checks columns
                  if(b == a[row][y])
                     sudoku= false;
                  else
                     continue;
               }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Blocks(int [][]b){//checks 3x3 blocks
        for(int d= 0; d< (b.length/3); d++){
             for(int e= 0; e< (b[d].length/3); e++){
                for(int d1= (d*3); d1< (b.length); d1+=3){
                   for(int e1= (e*3); e1< (b[e].length); e1+=3){
                      int bu= b[d1][e1];
                      for(int co=d1; co < 3; co++){
                         for(int col= e1 +1; e1< 3; e1++){
                            if(bu == b[co][e1])
                               sudoku= false;
                            else
                               continue;
                         }
                      }
                   }
               }
             }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce the behaviour you described.  I ran your code and it printed `false`.

Answer (score 0):

After Some research I think I solved my own problem. Also, sorry for the bad explanation for the problem

```
public class Sudoku{
private static boolean sudoku= true;
public static void main(String[] args){

  int input[][]= {{1,8,4,9,6,3,7,2,5},
                  {5,6,2,7,4,8,3,1,9},
                  {3,9,7,5,1,2,8,6,4},
                  {2,3,9,6,5,7,1,4,8},
                  {7,5,6,1,8,4,2,9,3},
                  {4,1,8,2,3,9,6,5,7},
                  {9,4,1,3,7,6,5,8,2},
                  {6,2,3,8,9,5,4,7,1},
                  {8,7,5,4,2,1,9,3,6}};

  RowXColumn(input);
  if(sudoku == true)
     Blocks(input);

  System.out.println("True or false, is this a sudoku puzzle solution: " + sudoku);

}
public static void RowXColumn(int [][]a){ 

  for(int row=0; row < a.length; row++){
     for(int col=0; col< a[row].length; col++){
        for(int x= row+1; x< a.length; x++){//Checks columns
           if(a[row][col] == a[x][col])
              sudoku = false;
        }
        for(int y= col+1; y< a[row].length; y++){//Checks rows
           if(a[row][col] == a[row][y])
              sudoku = false;
        }
     }
  }
}
public static void Blocks(int [][]b){

  for(int row= 0; row< (b.length); row+= 3){
     for(int col= 0; col< (b[row].length); col+= 3){

        for(int p= row; p< (row+2); p++){
           for(int p1= col; p1< (col+2); p1++){//picks out value to compare

              for(int comp= p1+1 ; comp < 3-p1; comp++){//compares
                 if(b[p][p1] == b[p][comp])
                    sudoku= false;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
 }
}
```